# Flow diagram from netlogo code

Tags: netlogo, flow-diagram

From NetLogo code is it possible to get a visual flow diagram of all procedures?
Observer procedures .. agent procedures .. and links between them.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking for [call graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph). Am I right?

I'm reasonably certain no such tool exists for NetLogo. (All of the tools we know about are listed on the [NetLogo resources page](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/resources.shtml).)

In [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/netlogo-devel/mDBskQMboYs/fGuJgdvw43gJ) it sounds like Glen Ropella was envisioning something like that, but if he got anywhere with it, I haven't heard about it.